# Close the hamburger menu when you click outside of container

Tags: jquery, hamburger-menu

I want to have a very simple hamburger menu. I'm using jQuery to toggle it to open and close when the hamburger is clicked. But I would like for the user to be able to close it when they click anywhere outside of the div or menu.

The [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nd96f398/) is what I have written out. Don't mind the styling.

I would like to use something like

```
$(window).on('click', function(){
    $('.responsive-menu').removeClass('expand');
})
```

But with that added, I cannot even open the menu. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Could we see the rest of your code and how you are integrating those lines please?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "anywhere outside the div"? Would you expect the menu to close if the user clicked a link or button on the page? Have you considered layering an invisible layer with width and height 100%, activating that onclick, then throwing the exposed menu on top of that?

Comment: @DavyM The lines are pure css

Comment: @TonyD So if the user clicks on the hamburger icon, the menu opens. If they click anywhere on the page, doesn't necessarily have to be a link or button, the menu will close.

Comment: this might be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800515/jquery-hide-dropdown-when-clicked-anywhere-but-menu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to check if the element clicked has a parent `.responsive-menu` or `.menu-btn`.

If it has'n any of the two and the menu is expanded, toggle!

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/j38xousa/)

```
$(document).on("click", function(e){
  if( 
    $(e.target).closest(".responsive-menu").length == 0 &&
    $(".responsive-menu").hasClass("expand") &&
    $(e.target).closest(".menu-btn").length == 0
  ){
    $('.responsive-menu').toggleClass('expand');
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your response. I never thought a simple case like that would work. Makes total sense!

Comment: It was a pleasure to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could add an overlay that is shown and covers your entire page.

You can add the empty markup `<div class="overlay"></div>` and using css hide it until your hamburger button is clicked. Then if you click the overlay, trigger the button click.

I updated your fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/nd96f398/2/

Comment: Hey! This worked perfectly as well. I will keep this in mind! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
const navOpen = 
document.getElementById("nav-open);

const navMenu = 
document.getElementById("nav-menu);

document.addEventListener( "click", (e) 
=> {
if(e.target.id !== "nav-open" && 
e.target.id !== "nav-menu") {
nav menu.classList.remove("show");
}
});
```