# How to enable sidebar to close if you click outside the menu bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, menu, sidebar

I would want to close the sidebar-menu when you click out side it. How do I achieve that?

My HTML code:

```
<nav class="menu" id="theMenu">
    <div class="menu-wrap sidebar">
        <span class="menu-close glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <h1 class="logo">&nbsp</h1>
        <!--<h1 class="logo"><a href="/#top" class="smoothScroll">Home</a></h1>-->
    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
        <li><a href="/" style="padding-left:8px;padding-top:8px;"> <i class="fa fa-home" title="Home"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="/auth/login"> <i class="svg-icon login-icon" title="Login"></i></a>  </li>
        <li><a href="/terms"><i class="fa fa-info" title="Resources"></i></a> </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You gotta use Javascript to achieve that...

Comment: you can achieve that from JS and provide full code of your sidebar so someone can solve it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery hide dropdown when clicked anywhere but menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800515/jquery-hide-dropdown-when-clicked-anywhere-but-menu)